# AngularJS binds unsafe:javascript:void(0) when value is javascipt:void(0)

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<a ng-attr-href="{{page==1 && 'javascript:void(0)' || '#a/'+tid+'/'+(page-1)}}">Prev</a>
```

I want to get that when page = 1

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Prev</a>
```

But the result:

```
<a href="unsafe:javascript:void(0)">Prev</a>
```

Comment: checkout $sce documentation, `$sce.trustAs...`

Comment: This is an interesting corner case behavior by Angular. However, if you only want to disable the action on the `a` tag, then have you considered using `ng-if` and returning `undefined` if `page == 1`?

Comment: I'll go with ng-if if this can not be done in this way.

Comment: You can try <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="function1()" >  prev </a>

Answer (score 7):

use **ng-click** on **a** and pass **$event** to your function.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="yourFunction($event);">Click</a>
```

In your function do the following

```
$scope.yourFunction = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
};
```

Answer (score 6):

new angular you have to white list javascript

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|javascript):/);
    }]);
```

or

```
<a href="#" ng-click="foo($event);">Click</a> 
$scope.foo = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
};
```

or

```
<a ng-click="foo($event);">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `ng-click` in `<a>`

```
<a href="" ng-click="go(tid)">
```

And in controller

```
app.controller('whatever', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.go = function(id){
       if($scope.page == 1) {
           return;
       }
       var url = '/a/' + id + '/' + ($scope.page - 1);
       $location.url(url);
    }
});
```

This way you also move logic out of template.

Comment: I don't wanna go with controller as I planning to use this template with multiple controller. And I am looking for a way to do it only in template!

Comment: Then you may be think for directive. This way you can reuse it in many places. But to have your logic in a template is not really good practice.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `href="javascript:void(0);";` try `href=""` or `href="#"` instead.